# Named virtual local host?

Tags: apache2

I've a local apache2 site which works if I have:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName localhost
...
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName localhost
```

in `.conf` file. So when I point browser to `localhost` I get to the site. How do I assign name to the site? E.g. I want `example.com` drive me there.

I tried to set the `ServerName` and `NameVirtualHost`:

```
NameVirtualHost 172.20.30.40:80
NameVirtualHost 172.20.30.40:443

<VirtualHost 172.20.30.40:80>
  ServerName www.example.com
...
<VirtualHost 172.20.30.40:443>
  ServerName www.example.com
```

But it doesn't work.

**Edit**:

I'm on linux (kubuntu).

**Edit 2**:

I also tried to

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName example.com
...
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName example.com
```

Also set `example.com` as the server name in the underlying database (postgresql). And in `/etc/hosts`:

```
127.1.0.0    example.com
```

After restarting my app and apache I expected `127.1.0.0` to reditect me to my site. When I actually point browser to `127.1.0.0` it tries to go somewhere but couldn't make it.

Comment: what's your OS (LINUX or WINDOWS) ?

Comment: you have to make a separate configuration for the ssl and do it with the file default-ssl.conf and later include that file in apache2.conf, in some case you have to create an ssl certificate too before get it works. good luck